# What does "user:something" mean in a javascript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

For example you can write `<a href="" onclick="javascript:.." >`
but what happens when you write `<a href="" onclick="user:4523234" >`

I just found this in an html code and i don't understand what it does.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's not something I've ever seen before.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: please post more code.

Comment: i can't post alot of stuff since it is work related code. I found something regarding protocols anyway... Found this javascript condition : "if(e.srcElement.protocol && (e.srcElement.protocol=='user:')" where e is an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens? Nothing.

It is just a [named label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

> **`label :    statement Parameters`**
>
> `label` Any JavaScript identifier that is not a reserved word.
>
> `statement`
>   Statements. break can be used with any labeled statement, and continue
>   can be used with looping labeled statements.

If it was an href, it would be a [custom protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers) like

```
<a href="mailto:foo@example.com">
```

Comment: Is there even a use case for inline named labels?

Comment: @DavidBarker: Sure, they are very helpful to escape from nested loops. Also, they can be used for various `break` statements.

Comment: if there is `onclick="javascript:foo();"`, was there an `onclick="vbscript:foo();"` also?